# Adding specific class to image_tag within link_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I wanted to add an image with text inside my `link_to` so I wrote this piece of code that is working fine :

```
<%=link_to image_tag('fleche_droite.svg') + "Ajouter un joueur à la liste", invite_player_path(@tournament), class: "btn btn-success", id: "convocation-submit" %>
```

the problem is that I need to add a specific class to my image to give it the right size. 
How can I do that within the rails helper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%=link_to image_tag('fleche_droite.svg', class: 'my_class') + "Ajouter un joueur à la liste", invite_player_path(@tournament), class: "btn btn-success", id: "convocation-submit" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use block to define content of your link, inside block add image_tag with class

```
<%=link_to invite_player_path(@tournament), class: "btn btn-success", id: "convocation-submit" do %>
   <%= image_tag('fleche_droite.svg', class: 'your-class-name') %>
<% end %>
```

See also [link_to helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)